Control MouseWheel speed with OnMouseWheel event
I am trying to detect mouseWheel event in my Dialog Box and control the speed of the mousewheel.
Below is the code snippet for normal mouseWheel movement:
static BOOL HandleMouseWheel(CWnd* pWnd, int nMode, int nDelta)
{
    int  nMsg[] = { SB_LINEUP, SB_LINEDOWN };
    int  nCmd[] = { WM_VSCROLL, WM_HSCROLL };
    bool bHorizontal = 0;
    int  nMax = bHorizontal ? 1 : 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < nMax; i++)
    {
        pWnd->PostMessage(nCmd[bHorizontal], nMsg[nDelta < 0], 0);
    }
    return 1;
}

BOOL OnMouseWheel(UINT nFlags, short nDelta, CPoint pt)
{
    return HandleMouseWheel(this, 1, nDelta);
}

The above code results in normal mouseWheel movement.
How to modify the code to reduce the speed of mousewheel?
Any help much appreciated.

nDelta is the distance the mouse wheel has been moved, so just divide nDelta by a value of your choice, until you get the desired "speed"

How to detect mouseWheel event scrolled in the ListBox control placed inside the parent DialogBox ?

@Monika I think you should ask a separate question, showing what you have tried / research.
